# Cancel sudo prompts in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I don't want 'sudo' to prompt me for password while my script is running. And i do not want to enter sudo password as well using sudo -S.
Is there any way to skip sudo lines and run next line of script.
Or is there any way to print 'sudo access required' whenever sudo is prompted and running the script further.

Comment: Comment those lines?

Answer (score 2):

You can test if the current user is root, like:

```
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "root access required"
    exit -1
fi
```

Comment: current user is not root. I'm running the script as normal user.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to prompt a sudo password, just add your current user to /etc/sudoers (edit this file as root).

Find there a block, starts from comment:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
```

And add there kind of this line:

```
YourUserName ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I want to run my script as a normal user. I don't want to run this as root user.

Comment: If you can run your script without sudo, just run it and you'll should not have any problem. If your script contains commands, which must run with sudo (e.g. service *some-service* restart), do what i wrote above, and sudo commands will pass without password.

When you run command from normal user with sudo - it means, that your user have root privileges, but you're not root.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, a better approach would be to just copy the script and edit it to a non-root version.

That said, if you create a function to implement your `sudo`'s that requires a flag be set you can activate them at runtime, but skip them by default.

```
$: cat tst
#! /bin/env bash

dosudo() {
   if (( DOSUDO ))
   then sudo "$@"
   else echo "Skipping: sudo $@"
   fi
}

echo before
dosudo ls -d /tmp
echo after
```

Running it in default mode:

```
$: tst
before
Skipping: sudo ls -d /tmp
after
```

Running it active (I CTRL-C break out of the prompt here) -

```
$ DOSUDO=1 tst
before
[sudo] password for weblogic:
after
```